# .scrollLeft() in div

Tags: jquery

I would like a div to .scrollLeft() to the .next() image every time I click the "next" link.

it works fine if I  have the document scroll ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/josiahmccracken/pgeQR/4/))
but if I want the div to scroll it becomes all wacky. ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/josiahmccracken/r6HwL/))

Answer (score 5):

`offset()` doesn't include the amount that the `div` is already scrolled. You need to account for that.

See [the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6HwL/7/).

I also made it so that the scrolling operates based on a index in the array as opposed to making a jQuery method call. This makes it execute (a little bit) faster.

Comment: so your solution was just adding the parent left to the next left for the scroll and it totaly works!

Answer (score 2):

Note that `.offset()` is [relative to the document](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) — this means that it depends on where the div is scrolled to already!

I'm not sure of the best thing to do instead (DOM position properties are hairy and lacking things that ought to be simple), but one that works is to use `.position()` instead, and establish an offset parent *within* the scrollable element (that is, an element which is relatively positioned and contains the images).

Changes to your code:

```
 $("#slides").animate({scrollLeft: $($current).position().left}, 500);
```

```
    <div id="slides">
        <div class="offset-parent"> <!-- added -->
            <img src="http://www.petwebsite.com/uploadpics/ginger-cat.jpg" class="images" alt="cat">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
.offset-parent {
    position: relative;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JF6xS/2/)

Comment: Huh. You fixed it by only changing the HTML and CSS and I fixed it by only changing the Javascript. More than one way to skin a cat I suppose.

Comment: No, I also used `.position()` instead of `.offset()`.

Comment: Oh yeah, you did. I just glanced real quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to do that much for it, I would suggest you to use **[slides](http://slidesjs.com/)** plugin or **[cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)** pluging, which will be the best way to do it according to me. Check the example on the plugin sites.

One more good plugin for this **[carousel](http://www.thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm)**